# How to turn off Colab’s Playground mode?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab for my recent project and I did see that the Colab’s auto-save feature is lagging my computer.

> So I turned on playground mode and then this problem occured(**not able to turn off playground mode in order to save(ctrl+s or command+s) the notebook**)

I am able to save the notebook by copying it in drive.

Any one knows how to turn off playground mode?

Comment: Playground only provides *temporary session* of your file, so notebook must be saved every time when you make changes within this mode. (And the easiest way is to save it on drive with the same name each time. Other options are to downlaod `.py` or `.ipynb` file to local machine.) 

That says, there cannot be a provision for turning off playground mode. Each time the notebook has to be saved to the drive with same or different name.

Answer (score 0):

If a notebook opens in playground mode, it means that you do not have permission to modify it. For example, this can happen when viewing a notebook hosted on Github, viewing a Google Drive notebook for which you don't have edit permission, or viewing a built-in Colab example notebook.

The only way to remove playground mode from such a notebook is to save a copy that you have permission to edit: the easiest way is to choose *File -> Save a copy in Drive*.